# Bootstrap’s Modal - change invoker attribute using input value from modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to obtain modal invoker and user input value introduced in my modal.

I know I can access invoker by doing this:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
});
```

And I can also get input value user introduced in my modal by doing this:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var color = $("#myModal #input-id").val();
});
```

But how can I fuse both things to obtain that value and based on it change invoker attribute.

My invokers:

```
<div style="background: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span>Some text<span/>
</div>
<div style="background: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span>Some text<span/>
</div>
<div style="background: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span>Some text<span/>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on my div, modal will trigger with some input text, after user enter value and press save button (data-dismiss="modal") I want to catch with js the input value and invoker and switch style attribute of invoker with input value user provided.

Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="MyNewModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Exit">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-id" class="col-form-label">Color:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-id">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I change `style` attribute of my invoker with user data introduced in my modal?

Comment: When would this happen on a tag? Was show.bs.modal and hidden.bs.modal already executed for it at least once?

Comment: I mean, when the user clicks on my div, modal will open with some input text, after user enter value and press exit button (data-dismiss="modal") I want to trigger js to get input value and invoker and switch style attribute with input value user provided for that invoker.

Comment: Steve, I am not a Bootstrap guru, this is why I am asking whether the two events where you can mine the information you need already happens when you need it. Because if so, then I have a very elegant solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @dwhite in his comment, if we want to access invoker after we exit modal, we need to save invoker in a variable in `show.bs.modal` event. This code does the job:

```
// Declare global variable
var invoker;

// On modal show event we save invoker
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
    console.log(invoker);
});

// When the user provides input and he exit modal, we get that value and we can
// access invoker to perform some actions
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    var color = $("#myModal #input-id").val();
    $(invoker).css('background', color);
    console.log(invoker);
    console.log(imageUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the style of you element by using jQuery’s `css` method,

```
var invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
invoker.css(<property>, <value>);
```

Simply modify the `<property>` with the style attribute that you want to change, followed by the `<value>` you wish to set.

If you want to access the style from the element, again you would use `css`, this time with just the `<property>`.

Comment: I don't know user value until he provides it in my modal and saves it (exit modal). As for I tested I can't access `e.relatedTarget` on `hidden.bs.modal` event.

Comment: You’re going to have to persist the value of the caller when it’s shown. You can do this with a variable or you could add a hidden or something to the modal to persist the calling element. Then use that to get the original caller.